# Unable to get custom property via Android Drive API

Tags: google-drive-android-api

Create a file and query file with custom property work fine, but it cannot retrieve custom property in queryChildren() ResultCallback.

Here is the CustomProperty definition:

```
/**
 * CustomPropertyKey: Uploaded file's hash code
 */
public static final CustomPropertyKey CustomPropertyKeyFileHash =
        new CustomPropertyKey("fileHash", CustomPropertyKey.PUBLIC);
```

query conditions:

```
            Query query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(
                        Filters.and(
                                Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, sMimeType),
                                Filters.eq(BaseDemoActivity.CustomPropertyKeyFileHash, mDriveFile.getMD5()),
                                Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)
                        )
                ).build();

            mDriveFile.getDriveFolder().queryChildren(mGoogleApiClient, query)
                .setResultCallback(mResultCallback);
```

query result callback:

```
            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
                    return;
                }

                MetadataBuffer mdb = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                if (mdb.getCount() > 0) {
                    try {
                        if (mdb != null) {
                            for (Metadata md : mdb) {
                                if (md == null) continue;

                                Log.d(TAG, "[FileMetadataCallback][onResult] md.getTitle(): " + md.getTitle() + ", md.getDriveId(): " + md.getDriveId());
                                Log.d(TAG, "[FileMetadataCallback][onResult] md.getTitle(): " + md.getTitle() + ", md.getResourceId(): " + md.getDriveId().getResourceId());

                                Map<CustomPropertyKey, String> map = md.getCustomProperties();
                                if (map != null) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "[FileMetadataCallback][onResult] file custom properties size: " + map.size());
                                    if (map.size() > 0) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "[FileMetadataCallback][onResult] file hash: " + map.get(CustomPropertyKeyFileHash));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (mdb != null) mdb.close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I always get log "**[FileMetadataCallback][onResult] file custom properties size: 0**". 
However, I should able to retrieve "mDriveFile.getMD5()" since it is one of query conditions, right?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Just found that it needs to wait a moment to get custom property properly after onCompletion callback.

Comment: Facing same problem and custom key plays an important role as i use it to avoid uploading files which are already uploaded by checking the id i set as custom property while uploading for first time. Any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that it needs to wait a moment (some minutes) to get custom property properly after onCompletion callback.
So this should be none issue if you don't need to get custom property immediately after onCompletion callback.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't expected. If the custom property was added on the file locally (i.e. on the same device where you are querying), you should be able to retrieve the properties without waiting for completion event. Can you try doing this when the device is offline?